# Retrieving More than 10,000 rows in Laravel App

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get all the rows from my mysql table which has 160000 rows of data and I want to pass that to REST API.

The app is built on Laravel and whenever I query, the server shuts down and app shows me internal server error, 500. I have tried to increase the memory limit for the app as well but it hasn't worked for me.

Laravel Eager Loading hasn't worked either. Is there a way to get all the rows of the table in the app?

Comment: did you check the laravel and sever logs ?

Comment: Try to get your error more specific.  Does it even involve MySQL?  Do we even know this right now?

Comment: I'll share my function with you.

I have a function that queries the database and get all the rows. The total rows returned are around 160,000. I convert those to json and print them out on the page. When I access the url to that page, the app stops running and server gives me Internal Server Error 500. 

So according to me the error is because the data returned is large and the server crashes. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Try **chunking** the results. Sample example of `chunk()` is

```
DB::table('users')->orderBy('id')->chunk(10000, function ($users) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        //
    }
});
```

For more information, [Chunking Results in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#chunking-results)